# React native icon to nav bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the `StackNavigator` from react-navigation. I want to add an icon on right corner in the navigation bar but how do I add it? Here is my code -

```
export const Routes = StackNavigator({
    MyList: {
        screen: MyList,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
            title: "MyList",
        }),
    },
   }
)
```

Comment: So what have you already tried exactly to add an icon?

Comment: I added the answer but onPress is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `props` `headerRight()` of `navigationOptions`

Example :

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
      headerTitle: <LogoTitle />,
          headerRight: (
             <Button
                onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
                title="Info"
                color="#fff"
             />
             ),
          };
       }
```

You can replace `Button` component with your required one

Fore more information [Refer this Link Headers Button React Native](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html)

**NOTE :**   **Kindly Use  components like  `Button` , `TouchableHighlight` , `TouchableOpacity` inside `headerRight()`. For more information of Handlaing Touches refer this link 
     [HANDALING TOUCHES](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches)**

==============================   **Example**           =================================

```
 class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

     constructor(props) {
        super(props)
     }

       static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
         return {
            headerRight: (
             <Button
                onPress={() => navigation.goBack() }
                title="Info"
                color="#fff"
            />
        ),
    }
};
```

If you want to use  `navigation` property inside right header button then you have to use bellowed give syntext and access that navigation property inside header right

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        headerRight: (

         ),
     }
  };
```

Here you can use

```
`navigation.goBack()`, `navigation.navigate("SCREN NAME")` etc..
```

Comment: But this.props.navigation.navigate is not working inside StackNavigator

Comment: create a method and add this code of navigation inside it and call this method from header...  right button

Comment: can you give me a example

Comment: I have added an example check and try again

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this -

```
headerRight: <Image source={require('xxx.png')} 
                onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('Next Screen') }} />
```

Comment: onPress()    is not the property of Image 
So its not going to work 
For that you have to use TouchableComnponent  .  Like  Button 
 , TouchableOpecity,TouchableHihlihts  etc...

Comment: But this.props.navigation.navigate is not working inside StackNavigator